# Is there a standard input voltage range for digital audio recording hardware?

Tags: audio-recording, digital, analog

If I'm recording digital audio on, say, a computer, whether I'm using a built-in line input jack or some fancy audio interface (assume I'm talking about *post*-gain amplification in the interface if it has got a gain adjustment), is there a standard range of input voltages that correspond to the minimum and maximum recorded values?

For example, if I record two signals that are both flat lines, one at the minimum value (e.g. 0 for 8-bit unsigned audio) and one at the max (e.g. 255 for 8-bit unsigned audio), and I assume there's no clipping, can I say what the input voltages were for those two signals on any reasonable audio recording interface (with the understanding that if there's a gain adjustment on the interface, this of course complicates things)?

---

A more subtle way of asking at least part of this question is: If I give the same audio signal to multiple different recording devices (all with the same input impedance) at unity gain, can I expect the same levels in the resulting digital recordings across all those devices? Assuming they are reasonable recording devices.

Then the other part of this question could be rephrased as: If I can expect the same levels between multiple devices, is there an industry-accepted voltage range for line level inputs where I'd expect to be able to record without clipping the results?

Comment: The answer to your question is in the spec sheets of ADCs, which makes me think that you should ask it on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ instead of here.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Some reasonably simplistic starting points - https://www.shure.com/en-EU/conferencing-meetings/ignite/tell-me-about-mic-and-line-level and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_level but yeah, this is more electronics than sound.

Comment: Note that flat lines are not signals. They would be interpreted as unwanted DC offset.

Comment: @audionuma Are you saying, it always varies by hardware then and there isn't a "traditional" range in audio recording? If so, I'd take that as an answer. :)

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for the links, those are useful.

Comment: @audionuma Btw, I wouldn't ask it on electronics.se, since it's not about a particular ADC part number (and if I'm going to disassemble all my audio interfaces to get part numbers, it's easy enough to check the datasheets). Rather, it's about what the typical ADC characteristics would be specifically in audio recording hardware, if there *are* typical characteristics. I'll read more about line and instrument level inputs and see if I come across some sort of commonly used value ranges.

Comment: A more subtle way of asking this question is: If I give the same audio signal to multiple different recording devices at unity gain, can I expect the same levels in the resulting recordings across all those devices? I've edited this into the question.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144367/discussion-on-question-by-jason-c-is-there-a-standard-input-voltage-range-for-di); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.